# How can I parameterise this method and make it more flexible?

Tags: c#, type-parameter

I'm writing a method to create Quartz scheduling jobs in C#. Currently it looks like this.

```
private async Task BuildJobs(int startHour, int endHour, int intervalOffsetSeconds = 0)
{
    try
    {
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<RepostTransactionsJob>()
            .WithIdentity(nameof(RepostTransactionsJob), TriggerGroup)
            .WithDescription("Reposting transactions")
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(string.Concat(nameof(RepostTransactionsJob), "-trigger"), TriggerGroup)
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(string.Format("{2:ss} {2:mm} {0}-{1} ? * * *", startHour, endHour, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalOffsetSeconds))))
            .Build();

        await this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.LogToLocal(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, I want to parameterise the `RepostTransactionsJob` part and I'm struggling. I've tried the following but that returns a build error.

Attempt:

```
private async Task BuildJobs<T>(int startHour, int endHour, int intervalOffsetSeconds = 0) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        var jobName = typeof(T).Name;

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
            .WithIdentity(jobName, TriggerGroup)
            .WithDescription("Reposting transactions")
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(string.Concat(jobName, "-trigger"), TriggerGroup)
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(string.Format("{2:ss} {2:mm} {0}-{1} ? * * *", startHour, endHour, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intervalOffsetSeconds))))
            .Build();

        await this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.LogToLocal(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Build error:

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as a type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'JobBuilder.Create<T>()' There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Quartz.IJob'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates, the [`JobBuilder.Create`](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/html/31e90849-355d-2b33-5776-3cd01522243e.htm) has a `IJob` constraint:

```cs
public static JobBuilder Create<T>()
where T : IJob
```

Therefore you need the same constraint on your method.

```cs
private async Task BuildJobs<T>(int startHour, int endHour, int intervalOffsetSeconds = 0) where T : IJob
```